# AngularJS multiple directives

Tags: angularjs

Ok, I'm being studying AngularJS for about a week now and I'm being able to make several mocks and small tests. I decided to try something deeper and build something close to a real application using AngularJS. Please take a look on the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UX6tmI5zYQ70cTnfzaG0?p=preview

My goal: There will be a treeview on the left column, a list of products in the center column, which is a list of items of a directive and product edit directive in the right column, something close to Microsoft Outlook. I'm being able to list the products in the center column, ok. In each item of listed in the center column, there is a link and what I want is clicking on this link will edit the product clicked in the right column. But how should I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A small tip: Why not just use `return {}` in your directive instead of `directive.scope`, `directive.restrict`, etc.

Comment: Gonna try that! Thanks! But do you have any suggestions on how to do what I want?

Comment: Not really, I am also a learner. Otherwise i'd be glad to help.

Comment: I think your columns are supposed to be: 1) tree view, 2) list view, 3) edit view. One problem I've noticed is you're using `onclick="yourFunc({{product}})`, which should be replaced with something like `ng-click="myFunc(product)"`. The latter will actually use a function named `myFunc` on scope. So within your controller, define a function like `$scope.myFunc = function(product) { console.log( product ); }`. I'd give you more details, but you've basically got a small application going on that Plunker.